# Angular 5 firebase database queries

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular-ngmodel

First of all I want to ask people who don't have time to just leave this post because this will take some time to read this. Secondly if you are still here I will try to explain the situation that I can't handle by myself.

- User log in (email, password) ***already did this**

Database :

```
Profile {
UID {
  email
  }
}
```

- User add his profile information (firstname, lastname, username, avatar) ***already did this**

Database :

```
 Profile {
    UID {
      email
      url
      firstname
      lastname
      username
        }
    }
```

- User add post*   ***already done this**

Database :

```
Profile {
   UID {
     email
     url
     firstname
     lastname
     username
        post* {
          name (file name)
          url (image url)
          progress(upload progress)

      }
   }
}
```

**What I want to do (tried hard, but can't)  :**

```
 Profile {
       UID {
         email
         url
         firstname
         lastname
         username
            post {
              name (file name)
              url (image url)
              progress(upload progress)
                 inner { //new
                    description //new
                    title //new
                    url (post image 1) //new
                    url (post image 2) //new
                    url (post image 3) //new
             }

          }
       }
```

- User clicks on one of his projects*
- User sees this.post *(only)* information *(post and inner)* on the other page*

***The code :*** 
https://github.com/codediodeio/angular-firestarter

I am using this code to make this. Simply I use ***upload service*** for creating new post. Main problem is that **I can't add any other strings to the upload.ts file**.

Tried :

- Added title, description uplaod.ts
- Wrote title and description with ngmodel (with observable upload)
- Nothing happens, or both inputs are undefined.

Upload.ts :

```
export class Upload {
  $key: string;
  file: File;
  name: string;
  title: string; //new
  description: string; //new
  url: string;
  progress: number;
  createdAt: Date = new Date();

  constructor(file: File) {
    this.file = file;
  }
}
```

Upload.service.ts :

```
 uploads: Observable<Upload[]>;


  pushUpload(upload: Upload) {
    const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
    const uploadTask = storageRef.child(`${this.basePath}/${upload.file.name}`).put(upload.file);

    uploadTask.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
      (snapshot: firebase.storage.UploadTaskSnapshot) =>  {
        // upload in progress
        const snap = snapshot;
        upload.progress = (snap.bytesTransferred / snap.totalBytes) * 100
      },
      (error) => {
        // upload failed
        console.log(error);
      },
      () => {
        // upload success
        if (uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL) {
          upload.url = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;
          upload.name = upload.file.name;
          this.saveFileData(upload);
          return;
        } else {
          console.error('No download URL!');
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

upload.form.ts :

```
   export class UploadFormComponent {

  selectedFiles: FileList | null;
  currentUpload: Upload;
  uploads: Observable<Upload[]>
  constructor(private upSvc: UploadService) { }

  detectFiles($event: Event) {
      this.selectedFiles = ($event.target as HTMLInputElement).files;
  }

  uploadSingle() {
    const file = this.selectedFiles;
    if (file && file.length === 1) {
      this.currentUpload = new Upload(file.item(0));
      this.upSvc.pushUpload(this.currentUpload);
    } else {
      console.error('No file found!');
    }
  }
}
```

upload.form.html :

```
         <h3>Single File Upload</h3>

          <label>
            <input type="file" class="button" (change)="detectFiles($event)">
          </label>
    <input [(ngModel)]="uploads.title" type="text">
 <input [(ngModel)]="uploads.description" type="text">
          <button class="button is-primary" [disabled]="!selectedFiles" (click)="uploadSingle()">
          </button>
```

Error (clear) :

> title and description are undefined.

It would be great if someone would explain me **what I am doing wrong with title and description** and would likely explain how to make these two things after that  :

- User clicks on one of his projects*
- User sees this.post *(only)* information *(post and inner)* on the other

***Thank you for your time.***

Comment: Please reduce the first part of your question (I have done this instead of this, this and this) to make your qeustion a bit shorter and better to read. Also include your actual databas structure and not a representation of it. And is this:   `description: strin; //new` a typo in your question or in the actual code of `upload.ts`?

Comment: It was typo when I wrote question, not from code.